# Generate random timestamp taking into account shift to daylight saving time

Tags: mysql, mariadb, timestamp

I want to generate random big data in MariaDB.
One of this columns is random timestamp which I generate like this:

```sql
select (current_timestamp 
        - interval (rand() * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10) second
       ) as record_time;
```

Since the end of March there is a shift to daylight saving time / summer time, so in one day there is no time from 02:00 to 03:00. And when I inserting this data I get error like:
**Incorrect datetime value: '2016-03-27 02:20:24.227322' for column db.tab1.record_time**.

How to modify this part of insert script to generate correct random timestamp values while accepting daylight saving time?

Link to [MariaDB info about timezones](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/datetime/)

Comment: Generate as datatime (without timezone), then convert to timezone which you need.

Comment: Thanks @Akina but it is possible to do this by sql operations? I cannot imagine exactly how I can do this, because every year is a day of time shift different.

Comment: Try to use `CURRENT_DATE` (or `CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE, ' ', CURRENT TIME)`). And what datatype does `db.tab1.record_time` have? If it is timestamp then use explicit CONVERT_TZ.

Comment: `db.tab1.record_time` is timestamp now. Any date or date + time is type of `datetime` and `datetime` also takes into account the time zone, so I can't randomly generate even a datetime, i need somehow detect invalid timestamp when inserting, but now it looks like I don't avoid using the procedure / trigger for fill this column with correct random data.

Comment: See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=6f795b823e5349b47340647cbbf00d0c)

Comment: Ok, i will check datetime this way. Linked documentation say that this is incorrect for datetime also, but probably I misunderstood it.  Anyway, I still don't know how to convert it back to my timezone and replace invalid times with valid ones. For 1 year it is easy, but i need it for random year.

Comment: *I still don't know how to convert it back to my timezone* [CONVERT_TZ() function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/convert_tz/). Use session time_zone value.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising... `select CONVERT_TZ('2016-03-27 00:20:24','+00:00','SYSTEM'), CONVERT_TZ('2016-03-27 01:20:24','+00:00','SYSTEM');` give me 1:20 and 3:20. I'll let you know if I found the final combination. Also `select timestamp '2016-03-27 02:20:24';` return 3:20.

Comment: Conversion between timezones working correctly for that date: `select CONVERT_TZ(((date '2016-03-28' - interval 21 hour) - interval (rand() * 60 * 60 * 3) second),'+00:00','SYSTEM');` give me times between 1:00 and 2:00 and then between 3:00 and 5:00. Thanks @Akina If you create an answer in this sense I will accept it.

Comment: *If you create an answer* No. I give general recommendations only (I'll tell you a secret - I did not understand anything in your specific problem). So I think you can create self-answer with detailed explaination what you have done and why it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert datetime from UTC to any timezone which apply correct shift to daylight saving time (UTC store datetime without any gaps so you can generate random time for UTC). Look at next select:

```sql
select CONVERT_TZ('2016-03-27 00:30:00','+00:00','+01:00') before_shift
     , CONVERT_TZ('2016-03-27 01:30:00','+00:00','+01:00') after_shift;
```

This select return `2016-03-27 01:30:00` and `2016-03-27 03:30:00`.
So, there is no time between `2:00:00` and `2:59:59` after timezone conversion.

According this question to generate random datetime you can use this select:

```sql
select convert_tz(
       current_date - interval (rand() * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10) second,
       '+00:00',
       'SYSTEM') as random_time;
```

Also check great answer from [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/251470/193061). He generate random timestamp based on random number converted from unix timestamp (seconds from fixed date). Example:

```sql
select FROM_UNIXTIME(
         UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp)
         - rand() * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10
       );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create timestamp in `SYSTEM` timezone with:

```sql
FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_in_seconds) -- This is a number, not a datetime
```

To convert back to a timestamp you can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function.

This sample demonstrate how to generate random datetime based on starting point. It give you only correct timestamps:

```sql
select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-03-27 00:30:00') + rand() * 10000);
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is also a good solution and easy to understand. I will expand this answer with example and vote up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you've not got time between 02:00 and 03:00, unless the server is an hour ahead maybe. BST jump happened at 01:00 when it jumped to 02:00, there was no hour between those times so you can't insert a datatime that falls in that hour, as it didn't exist.

Looks like yours did the jump at 02:00 to 03:00, that hour didn't exist so it won't let you insert time into that gap.

Comment: Link in my question accurately describes the situation when moving to summer time. It is also stated that the time shift takes place from the second hour to the third hour. I know there is no such time between 2:00 and 3:00 but I would like to randomly generate timestamps and skip this gap. How could I do that?